# Complaint Vs. Blame

Tags: functions

A question on our English test asked for the function of the following sentence:

“There is no hot water left, you shouldn’t have showered for too long!”

The correct answer was blame, but couldn’t it also be considered a complaint? Or both?
the person was obviously blaming the other one for showering for too long but wasn’t he also complaining about how there is no water? I really need a clear answer on this.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. I am not sure this question is about English usage;  it is perhaps more about social interaction.

Comment: Determining intention without context is really hard. The sentence could 'function' as *information*, *explanation*, *retort* (defending against an earlier accusation), *blame* or *complaint*, etc. The use of *too* instead of *so* only makes things worse. I'm not sure how your test was set up, but I don't think the question as written (*viz* pick either *blame* or *complaint* as *the* function of the quoted sentence) can be definitively answered either way.

Answer (score 2):

Had the sentence ended after the first clause, it would have been a **complaint**. But the second clause shifts the emphasis from the exhaustion of the hot water to the person responsible. That's **blame**.